# Upload directory by sftp

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I try to upload `localDir` to remote server i follow this guide [SFTP Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server)

but when upload the `localDir` and go inside i see **blankDir** I did the following

```
sftp> lls
404.html  crm nginx-logo.png  test.php

sftp> ls
 crm
     
sftp> put -r crm /usr/share/nginx/html
      Uploading crm/ to /usr/share/nginx/html/crm
      Entering crm/
```

**I created `crm` dir according to the following note in SFTP Guide**

> Note
>
> There is currently a bug in the versions of OpenSSH shipped with current >Ubuntu releases (at least 14.04 to 15.10) that prevents the above command >from operating correctly. Upon issuing the command above to transfer content >to a server using the buggy version of OpenSSH, the following error will be >given: Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory.
>
> To work around this issue, create the destination directory on the remote >end first by typing mkdir localDirectory. Afterwards, the above command >should complete without error.

but upload file working well.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: yeah i know the help guide for SFTP by `help or ?` i will update my que

Comment: I have all permissions , i uploaded file to this dir to check worked well

Comment: The same result 
`sftp> put -r crm
Uploading crm/ to /usr/share/nginx/html/crm
Entering crm/`


After `mkdir crm2` and `ls`  i see `crm2`

Comment: The **SFTP Guide** with my Que note us to create this dir look at `put section`

Comment: Yes, I see where it shows `put -r localDirectory` with the `localDirectory` in your case will be `/crm` but the location where you are uploading it to on the server (`/usr/share/nginx/html/`) the /crm is already there. If you're in `/usr/share/nginx/html/` then run `rmdir crm` and then do the `put -r crm` to see if it shows what you're expecting. I think the `/crm` is already where you are trying to upload it to, or I'm totally lost which is absolutely possible... put I do FTP stuff all the time... Perhaps the error isn't clear to me.

Comment: `sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /usr/share/nginx/html
sftp> lpwd
Local working directory: /var/www/nginx/html
sftp> put -r crm
Uploading crm/ to /usr/share/nginx/html/crm
Couldn't canonicalize: No such file or directory
Unable to canonicalize path "/usr/share/nginx/html/crm"
`

Comment: I noticed where it said the workaround to that issue you added to your answer is to make the directory first and then upload it. So you'd run `mkdir crm` and then run `put -r crm`.

Comment: I swear i did that  i created  `crm` before  uplodaing

Comment: this issue drive me to crazy , anyway you deserve  a big thank for your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Your Error**

[image]

To resolve your error per your comment, just run `mkdir crm` and then run `put -r crm`.

> The same flags that work with "get" apply to "put". So to copy an
>   entire local directory, you can issue:

```
put -r localDirectory
```

> Note
>
> There is currently a bug in the versions of OpenSSH shipped with
>   current Ubuntu releases (at least 14.04 to 15.10) that prevents the
>   above command from operating correctly. Upon issuing the command above
>   to transfer content to a server using the buggy version of OpenSSH,
>   the following error will be given: `Couldn't canonicalise: No such file or directory.`
>
> To work around this issue, create the destination directory on the
>   remote end first by typing `mkdir localDirectory`. Afterwards, the above
>   command should complete without error.